# sync the 2 tables for certain rows

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a question of is it possible and should i try to do it?

i have two rows in my table one named jobs and one named contacts (hope you still with me)

in jobs i have the following columns

```
typeofjob
id
name
phone
address
budget
due
```

in contacts i have the following columns

```
id
name
phone
address
```

is there a way to sync the 2 tables for certain rows?

```
id
name
phone
address
```

i ask as this would make life a lot easier for me but worried as id might conflict

and what happens if i delete a user from contacts i would only want it deleted from that row

i am very new to this and learning so if you can answer me with simplify answers that be great just treat it like your trying to explain this to your nan or something, but on the other hand she might pick this up faster than i am :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want as an ID in one of the columns with an ID of a row in another table. So, you could add a column `contact_id` in `jobs` table, under the assumption that each contact could potentially spawn multiple jobs. You can then query it, such as

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `contact_id` = 'whatever'
```

You could also use [JOINS](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) to do more complex and efficient work (remember, the less trips to the database, the better!).

Comment: so basicly i create a coloum named "clientid" in my jobs and inter join it with my contacts id?